# How to write input files with comments in Python

Tags: python, comments

I need to write some input data files for a python program, and I need the full thing:

comments, spacing, variable = value, etc.

Is there any library (line argparser for command line arguments) for python or should I write my own?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use pure Python modules as "data files". They support comments, spacing, variable assignment and more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module (renamed to `configparser` in Python 3).

Alternatively, you could simply write the input data using Python syntax, and `import` the result into your main program.

Answer (score 0):

Does the syntax have to look like that? Could you just use a character delimited file (like csv or tab-delimited) with each predefined field in a separate column? Python has well defined modules to handle `csv` data.

If you specifically want input files that present blocks of code, then aix's suggestion of importing would also work.